# Understanding strange array return

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am struggling to understand the following:

```
var foo = [100, 2],
    bar = foo;

bar[0] = 9;

console.log(foo[0], bar[0]); // returns => 9, 9
```

I understand `bar[0]` returning 9 as it's set at that - but how is `foo[0]` returning 9, instead of returning 100?

It seems like `foo` has become `bar`, therefore setting it right to left, not left to right

Comment: `bar = foo;` creates reference `bar` to `foo` it is not full copy. if you need copy of `foo` you can use `.slice` - `bar = foo.slice()`

Comment: `bar` stores the reference of `foo` hence if bar is changed then foo will change too...If you do not want them to be changed then use deep copy of elements!

Answer (score 4):

Here `foo` and `bar` both points to the same location in memory. The actual array is shared between the variables. So, basically they both access/update the same array.

Non-primitive datatypes are not passed by value, they are passed by reference.

```
_______                _______
| foo | --> [...] <--  | bar |
|     |                |     |
-------                -------
```

To copy array, use `slice`.

```
var bar = foo.slice();
```

Answer (score 0):

`foo` is assigned by reference to `bar` variable. if you want to assign it by value use:

```
bar = foo.splice(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

as you have assign the foo variable to bar and both are sharing the same memory location hence the result is same.